# When are mean and variance estimates uncorrelated or independent

Tags: probability, distributions, correlation, independence, estimators

I know that in the case of the normal distribution, the MLE estimates of the mean and the variance are independent. My impression is that this is a rare property for a distribution to have. Are there any known results that guarantee this property or the weaker condition of being uncorrelated, or are there other well-known distributions with these properties?